# What are the server side scripting languages supported in ASP and in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have searched in google about it, some people telling that ASP support only VBScript and ASP.Net support VBcript and Javascript. And some  others telling ASP support VBScript and Javascript and ASP.Net also same. Tel me clearly
**What are the scripting languages support in  in ASP and in ASP.Net** What about JScript and is there any scripting languages are ther which supports in ASP or ASP.Net.
Thank you

Comment: Client side or server side?

Comment: Client side scripting support is totally browser feature and does not depend on server technology. The only scripting language for browser which is wide supported is JavaScript.

Comment: If you're asking about client-side, why does your subject say server-side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Older *Classic ASP* pages can be written in any language that supports Microsoft's *Active Scripting* technology, typically:

- VBScript
- JScript (Microsoft's dialect of Ecmascript)

*ASP.Net* pages can be authored in any supported .Net language, typically:

- C#
- VB.NET

These are all Server Side languages, so called because they execute on the web server.

Any server side language can output script for the browser execute on the client side, this is typically JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

For **server side** languages:

Classic ASP uses JavaScript (or rather JScript, the Microsoft version) or VBScript as server side scripting language.

ASP.Net doesn't really use a "script" language, as it is compiled. You can use any .Net language. Often VB.Net or C# is used.

Server-side code is used to generate HTML code (among other processing such as interacting with a database). When the server processing is done the resulting HTML code is sent to the browser where the page is displayed according to that definition. The server can not react again unless the page is submitted.
For speedier reactions, client-side javascript may be used. The importance of javascript for a particular page can range from hardly any (maybe some input validation) to a huge amount (like in gmail).

Answer (score 2):

You can write ASP.NET Applications in:

- C#
- VB.NET
- F#
- ... Any .NET supported language

You can write Classic ASP applications in

- VBScript
- JScript
- [Perl](http://www.apache-asp.org/) - Interesting eh?

Client side you can use whatever the browser supports.